# Eclipse cannot start due to osgi framework bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have issues to start up my Eclipse.
Looking in the error log show problems to start osgi framework bundle(osgi.framework.BundleException).

I found a site that describes how to debug OSGI.

1. Create a trace file (.options) used for setting debug/tracing
   options
2. Added following to the eclipse.ini
   (-Dosgi.debug=C:\tracing.options )
3. Added tracing options to the tracing file: org.eclipse.osgi/debug
   /bundleLoad=true

I had expected some kind of extended logging in .options, but nothing is added when I start Eclipse.

Any hint of what I am missing.

Comment: I don't set `bundleLoad` in the list of valid OSGi plug-in debug options.

Comment: What was the exception in startup?

Comment: @Neil Barlett it is following.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)

 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 t org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.createProtectionDomain(ModuleClassLoader.java:359)

Comment: Ok finally solved my issue.
I changed  heap size  to 6 GB in eclipse.ini . 
-Xms6000m
-Xmx6000m

Earlier it was following.
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m